# Button loop repeats the same buttons many times, and .delete fails

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, button

I have some buttons on a sheet that are created using a macro, each time a new item is added (essentially, they're a "delete this row" button, and a "create list" button).

I wrote a macro using a `For Each`/`Next` loop to delete all buttons intersecting with the range of the shape I click on, but it wasn't working.

I added a bunch of `Debug.Print` commands to see what was happening, and I'm very confused by the result.

The For Each loop is hitting the same buttons over and over again, and even when the button is identified as intersecting the range, the delete function fails and the loop repeats that same button again.

**I have 2 Questions:**

1. Is there any way to prevent my For Each loop from repeating the same buttons over and over? and
2. What am I doing wrong that the buttons aren't deleting?

---

**Here's my code:**

```
Sub DeleteBtn()
    Dim i As Integer   'variable to keep track of how many loops we've done

    'returns the number of entries on my sheet
    NumTasks = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Tasks").Range("B7:B10000"))
    'uses the clicked shape to position the macro
    Set rctngl = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    'using topleftcell, this creates an address reference for the shape that called the macro
    With rctngl.TopLeftCell
        'sets this variable to hold the characters in the address for the clicked shape
        rctnglAdd = .Address
        ''''show shape address in immediate window
        Debug.Print "Rectangle location is " & rctnglAdd
        ''''sets this variable to hold the integer value of the clicked shape row
        rctnglRow = .Row
        ''''show shape row value in immediate window
        Debug.Print "Rectangle row is " & rctnglRow
        ''''sets a range to check against for button deletion
        Set btnRng = Sheets("Tasks").Range("$M$" & rctnglRow & ":$N$" & rctnglRow)
        ''''show range to check for intersect
        Debug.Print "Intersect Range is " & btnRng.Address
    End With

    i = 1     ''''sets i to 1 for the first time through the loop
    For Each btn In Sheets("Tasks").Buttons  ''''begin loop for every button in the sheet
        On Error Resume Next   'ignore errors
        newName = btn.Name    ''''This instance name is
        newAdd = btn.TopLeftCell.Address  ''''this instance address is
        Debug.Print "Round " & i & "!"   ''''Show loop number in immediate window
        ''''Show this instance address in immediate window
        Debug.Print "This Button's address = " & newAdd
        ''''Show this instance name in immediate window,
        Debug.Print "This Button's Name = " & newName
        ''''if this instance intersects with intersect range
        If Not Intersect(Range(newAdd), btnRng) Is Nothing Then
            ''''message to say button intersects
            Debug.Print "Button address " & newAdd & " intersects with delete range " & btnRng.Address
            ''''message to say button will be deleted
            Debug.Print "Deleting Button: " & """" & newName & """"
            ActiveSheet.Buttons("""" & newName & """").Delete ''''Original code was btn.delete
        End If
        i = i + 1     ''''increase i for next loop
    Next btn          ''''begin loop for next

End Sub
```

**And here's what the Immediate Window shows when I run it on my sheet with 4 buttons:**

```
Rectangle location is $N$8
Rectangle row is 8
Intersect Range is $M$8:$N$8
Round 1!
This Button's address = $M$5
This Button's Name = Button 1139
Round 2!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 3!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 4!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 5!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 6!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 7!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 8!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 9!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 10!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 11!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 12!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 13!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 14!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 15!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 16!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 17!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 18!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 19!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 20!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 21!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 22!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 23!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 24!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 25!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175 
Round 26!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 27!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 28!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 29!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 30!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 31!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 32!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 33!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 34!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 35!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 36!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
Round 37!
This Button's address = $M$5
This Button's Name = Button 1139
Round 38!
This Button's address = $N$5
This Button's Name = Button 1144
Round 39!
This Button's address = $M$7
This Button's Name = Button 1175
Round 40!
This Button's address = $M$8
This Button's Name = Button 1215
Button address $M$8 intersects with delete range $M$8:$N$8
Deleting Button: "Button 1215"
```

Comment: try looping through backwards and deleting from the last to the first

Comment: @Scott, Forgive my ignorance, but I don't know how to run this backward.

I tried: `With Sheets("Tasks")` `For i = Sheets("Tasks").Buttons.count To 1 Step -1` `newAdd = Buttons(i).TopLeftCell.Address` `If Not Intersect(Range(newAdd), btnRng) Is Nothing Then` `.Buttons(i).Delete` `End If` `Next` but it didn't work.

@GMalc, part of the purpose of this code is to remove buttons which may be on top of each other. I don't know of a way to easily tell how many buttons may be intersecting with a range. Even if your explanation were accurate for $M$8, it still doesn't explain $N$5, $M$7, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me after several tests **using MS Forms Buttons**. The below code did not recognize **ActiveX Buttons**.

Notice, especially that I removed `On Error Resume Next`. You can never debug code with that statement in effect because it will ignore all errors.

```
Sub buttons()

    Dim btnRng As Range
    Set btnRng = Sheets("Tasks").Range("A1:Z100")

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1     ''''sets i to 1 for the first time through the loop

    Dim btn As Object
    For Each btn In Sheets("Tasks").buttons  ''''begin loop for every button in the sheet


        Dim newName As String
        newName = btn.Name    ''''This instance name is

        Dim newAdd As String
        newAdd = btn.TopLeftCell.Address  ''''this instance address is

        Debug.Print "Round " & i & "!"   ''''Show loop number in immediate window
        ''''Show this instance address in immediate window
        Debug.Print "This Button's address = " & newAdd
        ''''Show this instance name in immediate window,
        Debug.Print "This Button's Name = " & newName
        ''''if this instance intersects with intersect range


        If Not Intersect(Sheets("Tasks").Range(newAdd), btnRng) Is Nothing Then
            ''''message to say button intersects
            Debug.Print "Button address " & newAdd & " intersects with delete range " & btnRng.Address
            ''''message to say button will be deleted
            Debug.Print "Deleting Button: " & """" & newName & """"
            btn.Delete
        End If

        i = i + 1     ''''increase i for next loop

    Next btn

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! This solved my problem. I ended up using my "i" counter against a second "i2" variable to hold the buttons.count to keep the loop from restarting at the end.

`i = 1` `i2 = Sheets("Tasks").buttons.count` `For Each btn In Sheets("Tasks").buttons` `newAdd = btn.TopLeftCell.Address`
`If Not Intersect(Sheets("Tasks").Range(newAdd), btnRng) Is Nothing Then` `btn.Delete` `End If` `If i >= i2 Then GoTo jmp` `i = i + 1` `Next btn` `jmp:` `End Sub`

Thank you thank you thank you!